# How would someone who needs to read a story from A to Z be qualified?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When I'm beginning to watch a movie, or read a book, I tend to want to watch or read the whole story through, even if it is a story of questionable quality or if I know the end. And I don't want to miss a thing. What would be an adjective to qualify such a person like me?

Comment: Do you mean "describe" insread of "qualify"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjective to describe your not wanting to miss anything might be *obsessive*, since you are *obsessed* about reading every word of the book and watching every second of the movie.

Comment: You definitely hit the mark with _obsessive_, would there not be a word to describe someone with the _obsession_ to know how the event unfold in a story?

Comment: I think `obsessive`, despite the potential negative connotations, is the right word.

Answer (score 4):

How about *dedicated* or *devoted*?

In gaming circles, the term *completionist* is quite popular.

Comment: I'm not sure dedicated/devoted fit best, but *completionist* definitely fits the bill. Not sure how well it translates outside of gaming circles. I think you'll find your *completionists* are one and the same with Jasper's *obsessives*! :)

Answer (score 2):

In the sense that you are determined to finish, even in the face of something that might be disappointing, I would suggest *tenacious*.

Comment: I think the word as too much a negative, like I don't want to do it, whereas I'm actually enjoying it in a way.

Comment: I think `tenacious` is going a bit too far perhaps, but I disagree with Eldros that it is a negative word - tenacity is an admirable quality in my book...

Comment: I don't think tenacious is negative. It's just that it describes a quality beyond the ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm like that too. I like to describe myself as *obsessively curious*.

Answer (score 1):

I see this more in the case of multiple installments, but try "completist": "He's such a completist that he's still reading $series even though it hasn't really been good since book 13".

Answer (score 0):

I would say *somebody with determination*, using *determination* with the meaning of *firmness of purpose*.
As alternative, I would use *indefatigable*, *steadfast*, or *diligent*.

Answer (score 0):

The trait is a form of perfectionism, drawing on the root meaning of *perfect* as complete. The desire for completeness overshadows competing priorities of how to use one's time.